# Scroll-bar is not visible in <div> in WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I have Html File Containing a Scroll Division. When I add this HTML in WebView, it doesn't shows the scroll-bar for that div.

I have code in Html file.

```
// some Html code


<table style="border: 3px solid black;" align="center">
 <tr>
<td ><div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; overflow: auto;  padding:0px; "> <div>
  put returns between paragraphs
► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
► _italic_ or **bold**
► indent code by 4 spaces
► backtick escapes `like _so_`
► quote by placing > at start of line
► to make links
<http://foo.com>
 [foo](http://foo.com)
► basic HTML also allowed

 </div></td>
</tr>
</table>

// some Html code
```

When I add This Html file in WebView in xml File.

code of XMl is...

// some Html code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/webLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleLayout" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

// some Html code

It Works fine but doesn't shows the Scroll-bar for that Div which was added in Html file

Comment: have you tried using WebChromeClient?

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling a div with `overflow:auto` is currently not available on the Android.
But you can achieve the same with some work around using a combination of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. See [this](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=147) link for the details.

Another solution is, you can use the [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) library.

And for your information, [here is a nice comparison of what may or may not and how work on various mobile browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html).

Comment: I seen the Comparison but i want any alternate solution for that.

Comment: I have already suggested two workarounds in my answer above. Have you tried them?

Comment: I seen your answer but i don't want buttons to scroll. I want normal touchable and scrolable view without buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1327047). They disabled rendering scrollbars so that the native-rendered scrollbars wouldn't conflict with browser scrollbars. But that disabled rendering *all* scrollbars.

Fixing this would apparently be a big deal due to the backward-compatibility thicket that is WebView. You can head over and star the bug and that would signal that people actually want it fixed.